# Delete google drive files by extension with PyDrive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I'm trying to delete all files with the extension '.pdf' from a google drive folder.
Everything is fine with the API authentication, I can upload the files. The problem is being the delete.

Here I upload

```
upload_file = 'Test1.pdf'
gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': '11SsSKYEATgn_VWzSb-8RjRL-VoIxvamC'}]})
gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
gfile.Upload()
```

Here I try to delete

```
delfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': '11SsSKYEATgn_VWzSb-8RjRL-VoIxvamC'}]})
filedel = "*.pdf"
delfile.SetContentFile(filedel)
delfile.Delete()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/linol/Documents/ProjetoRPA-Python/RPA-TESTE.py", line 40, in <module>
    delfile.SetContentFile(filedel)
  File "C:\Users\linol\Documents\ProjetoRPA-Python\venv\lib\site-packages\pydrive\files.py", line 175, in SetContentFile
    self.content = open(filename, 'rb')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '*.pdf'
```

Comment: Why not start google colab, connect to drive and run `!find '/content/drive/MyDrive' -type f -name '*.pdf' -delete`?

Comment: The codes above are only part of almost 100 lines of code. I'm using PyCharm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to delete the files of PDF file in the specific folder.
- You want to achieve this using pydrive for python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Drive using Drive API.

In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve file list of PDF file from the specific folder.
2. Delete the files using the file list.

When above flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please modify `###` to your folder ID.

```
# 1. Retrieve file list of PDF file from the specific folder.
fileList = drive.ListFile({'q': "'###' in parents and mimeType='application/pdf'"}).GetList()

# 2. Delete the files using the file list.
for e in fileList:
    drive.CreateFile({'id': e['id']}).Trash()
    # drive.CreateFile({'id': e['id']}).Delete() # When you use this, the files are completely deleted. Please be careful this.
```

- This sample script retrieves the files using the mimeType. When you want to retrieve the files using the filename, you can also use `fileList = drive.ListFile({'q': "'###' in parents and title contains '.pdf'"}).GetList()`.
- **IMPORTANT**: In this sample script, when `Delete()` is used, the files are completely deleted from Google Drive. So at first, I would like to recommend to use `Trash()` instead of `Delete()` as a test of script. By this, the files are not deleted and moved to the trash box. By this, I thought that you can test the script.

#### Note:

- It seems that PyDrive uses Drive API v2. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [PyDrive](https://github.com/googleworkspace/PyDrive)

Comment: I did the process above, researching the references, the code does not generate an error, but does not delete the files.

Comment: When trying a print (filelist), nothing returns in the terminal

Comment: @Lino Costa Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. In my environment, when I tested above script, I can confirm that the files can be deleted. I apologize for this. From `When trying a print (filelist), nothing returns in the terminal`, in this case, it seems that the files are not retrieved. I think that the reason of your current issue is due to this. So, can you confirm your current script and your folder again? When PDF files are put in the folder, the filelist has the value.

Comment: @Lino Costa For example, if your PDF file has no mimeType of `application/pdf`, when you test `fileList = drive.ListFile({'q': "'###' in parents and title contains '.pdf'"}).GetList()` that I have already mentioned, what result will you obtain? By the way, your folder is in the shared Drive or your Google Drive?

Comment: I will do the rest of the tests now. The files are in a shared folder on Google Drive

Comment: I managed to solve ... I needed to create a new 'credentials_file' and change the 'oauth_scope' in settings.yaml. After that, the code worked well. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Lino Costa Thank you for your response.